# Cannot select tester on iTunes Connect "Add Existing Testers to Build"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

My user role is admin and legal. As you can see (because it's highlighted) from the screenshot I have clicked on one of the testers.  In the right hand corner the "next" button is still not able to be clicked.

Any help would be great thanks!

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WKQ5.png)

Comment: I found that adding `Individual Testers` does not seem to work. 1.) Make sure the user is added to `Users and Roles` as a `developer`. 2.) Add them to `App Store Connect Users`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56303470/481207

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. After struggling for a bit, I found the solution was to remove all the users from the "iTunes Connect Users" group and then re-add them from existing users. Then I was able to send an invite to start testing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had this problem in 2020. The names have changed, but removing all the users from the "App Store Connect Users" list, and then re-adding them worked. After that I was able to select the users and the Next button was enabled. It might be because the users were added before we had any apps.