# iTunesConnect Testflight no builds available for iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am having trouble adding an admin to one of my iOS builds.

When I click to my build, it shows I have 2 people who can test it:

[image: iTunes Connect Users]

But this is not what I'm expecting.  I am expecting 3 people.  Because if I click to the ITunesConnect Users, I see 3 people.

[image: Testers]

But for some reason, my friend `Yu Yu` shows `No Builds Available`.  Why is this the case?  Under the Users and Roles, I can confirm that Yu Yu is an admin

[image: No builds available]

What am I doing wrong?  How do I allow `Yu Yu` to see my build `10 (23)` ?

Comment: [1] Is yu yu an iTunes Connect user? [2] On screenshot two, there's a "Builds" tab, what is displayed there? [3] Maybe try removing yu yu from their group/role and re-add them.

Comment: Yes Yu Yu is an itunesconnect user.  Under the builds tab, I see build for `10 (23)`

Comment: Yu Yu is able to login to itunes connect via website with her yuyu email address and see all my apps, including the app intended for this question.

Comment: You could try "Add Testers to Build" on screenshot one perhaps. The only other suggestion would be to remove them from their role and re-add them. Sounds like a bug almost on iTunes Connect.

Comment: WHen i tried "Add Testers to Build", i used Yu Yu's email address.  Itunes then gave me the error `You’ve already added this email address, so this tester wasn’t added.`

Comment: Is your build new or was it existing before Yu Yu was added to a role? From my understanding if the build comes before she was added then you'll have to create a new build for her to be able to test it. ( possibly helpful info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046744/i-cant-add-testers-to-itunes-connect-users-and-roles-%e2%86%92-testflight-beta-testers )

Comment: The `app` was made before Yu Yu was added as an admin.  This current version and build `10 (23)` was created after Yu Yu was added as an admin.  Yu Yu was added as an admin aroudn the time `10 (21)` was created, but Yu Yu was never able to access any of these builds.  This problem has never been resolved.

Comment: Okay, then that's definitely not the issue ( I read that on the last thing I linked ). Did you try removing and then re-adding her role in the iTunes Connect?

Comment: thanks, i'll try that a bit later.  In the meantime, I've got another problem with testflight/itunesconnect in case you have any suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735018/itunesconnect-test-flight-does-not-show-recent-builds-even-though-simulators-and

Answer (score 76):

I had this as well. I removed the users from the test group (I did not delete them from TestFlight) and then re-added them. That gave me the "resend invite" option, which I used. The testers received the new invite, and were able to install the build.

Comment: Same happened to me as well. I think it happens when you add users before you've added a build because the 1 user I added after I added the build got the invite. Removing the clitched once and re-adding them worked.

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra, I think that you're right: it happens to users that you have added before you add the first build. I haven't seen it on subsequent builds. Of course, you have to have at least one user to add the build.

Comment: I just want to elaborate on this a bit, my issue was testers in the 'App Store Connect' user group had "No build available" because I added my testers before I added the build. I removed the users from the app store connect testers and re-added them and the invite was sent.

Comment: Working ... Thanks

Comment: It is November 2019, and this worked for me as well

Comment: Apple: Largest net capital company in the world. Apple developer admin UI: Completely broken, buggy and undocumented. Great!

Answer (score 18):

I had same issue. For me, I simply had to go under "BUILDS" > click the + mark next to Builds(0) and actually click the check mark next to my build, then it allowed me to "add" the build for my "new" user. I don't know if this is your issue or if it will help, but it was my solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect , I had created a new group ➕ (External) after we had started testing the build and I hadn't noticed the Build Tab which shows the builds available to the group.  Once I had added the Build as advised and shown above ☝ and refreshed the page the invitation changed to invited.

Comment: Apple console is so much disgusting. No logic behind their UX and each time I want to do something after a period, a new problem raise. They change their designs and logics in an unuseful way

Answer (score 13):

Gu to App Store Connect Users
[image: Store Connect Users]

and check your testers email

[image: Add App Store Connect Users]

Comment: This is the correct answer. 1.) Make sure the user is added to `Users and Roles` as a `developer`. 2.) Add them to `App Store Connect Users`. Note: adding `Individual Testers` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 9):

As of early 2019 If your build is newly uploaded to AppStoreConnect then it will take a few hours to go through Apple's quick testing review before it becomes available in TestFlight management view. If you invited the tester before that, you'll need to re-invite him/her and the build will be available for the user.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your user doesn't have access to a specific app.
Go to `Users and Access` then select the user > Apps section. And add a tested app (allow user to test it). Worked for me if you tried all other answers.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add "**App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption**" key to the info.plist and set it **NO**. Then upload a new build.

Comment: Re-adding internal testers and uploading a new build did not work and I continued to have "No builds available."  Can confirm this compliance key/value worked for several of us.  This issue arose sometime in February 2020 and seems to be a bug with manually reporting compliance through appstore connect.

Here is an active discussion with multiple bug filings to Apple: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/128891

Comment: This key-value solution fixed my problem. Of course, it may be other issues that cause this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same trouble with a group of testers, what fixed it for me was removing the group's access to the build, then re-adding it.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with getting test users assigned to my new build. It just kept stating "no build available" for my users. After trying several things, eventually an email appeared from testflight to all my users. So it seems even though a build was available, I had to wait a couple hours. After that, the users had the build assigned to them already in app store connect.

Answer (score 0):

The same `No Builds Available` message happened to me when I added a new build with the `Notify Users` option unchecked (I didn't want to spam the whole group, I just wanted a new user who I was in contact with by email to have access to the beta build).

The quick solution (provided by Apple Support) was to go to appstoreconnect, Testflight > iOS/tvOS/watchOS, select the `Builds` tab and select the `Notify Testers` button on the approved build.

It seems you have to notify everyone in a group, or no-one can access the new build :(

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I had the "No builds" user in an another, public testing group too, because he clicked the invite link once. He could be seen as an "Anonymous" user in that group. Removing the anonymous user and readding him as a developer solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check also if the email is registered at Apple.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answered worked for me. After going back and forth with Apple I finally got a build in TestFight by removing the Silicon Mac option (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65026451/1459666) and resubmitting a new build. It then gave me the option in `App Store Connect Users -> Testers -> Status` to resend invitations to the testers. Upon accepting the invite it uploaded to my TestFlight app.

Answer (score 0):

I added tester to the Internal Group(instead of clicking on the build and add external testers) --> App Store Connect User and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the above solution, but which worked for me is to give `testers` access as a `developer`

Follow the below steps:

1. Open link https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users
2. Click on the + button to add a new user
   [image]
3. Fill in some basic details of the user and mark it as a developer(you can select anything, but that I haven't tried so not sure if it will work or not)

[image]

4. Now, Go to TestFlight and select **App Store Connect Users** which appeared In the left side panel, and add the new user as a tester here. That's it :)

**Note:** if it still not working then go inside uploaded build and add a user from **Groups** or **Individual Testers** option

Answer (score -1):

Solution,

If you are facing **No Builds Available** issue in testflight then please follow my instruction to solve the problem.

1. Firstly make sure that at least one build has to be approved by the apple team
2. If not then you will have to wait to approval it.
3. Support you have uploaded a build 1.0 and they have approved for the testing but you are not a tester for that build
4. Now you upload 2.0 build and you are facing **No Builds Available** issue.
5. ***Now you have to add your email address into 1.0 build for the testing then you add again email into 2.0 build which you just uploaded***
6. The scene behind is that you can't test any build until they approve it but if you are an existing test and you are testing one of the previous builds then you can access the latest build also using above 5 point

I hope it will help you