# itunesconnect test flight does not show recent builds even though simulators and USB works fine

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight

Four months ago, I built a demonstration react-native app and deployed it to test users via test flight.  Everything worked fine.

Today, I decided to return to work on my app.  I changed the version number to 10 and build number to 23 as shown in this image here:

[image]

Then I worked on the actual code.  I've completely re-styled the interface and functionality.  In XCode, I pressed Product>Clean, then I pushed it to my iOS simulators for iPhone 7, 8 and X.  Everything worked perfectly.  I connected some iphones via USB to my mac mini and deployed over the USB.  Again everything worked perfectly on the actual phones.

So then I switched to `Generic iOS Device`:

[image]

Then I pressed Product>Clean, and then I pressed Product>Archive.   The xcode Window>Organizer appeared.  I then pressed a button to `Upload to App Store...`.  I put in my password, the upload progress completed, and no errors occurred.

A few minutes later, I see my new build available in TestFlight.  I've asked my QA people to download and test the build.  **They said that although the see the new Splash Screen I created (aka LaunchImage.storyboard), everything else about the app is the code from several months ago.**

I went into Test Flight and I EXPIRED all past builds.   I then went to xCode Window>Organizer and I deleted all past builds.  I changed the build number. I then went to Product>Clean.  Then I went to Product>Archive.  Then I uploaded the app via Window>Organizer.

But again, all QA people who downloaded the next build/version still see the old app that I built 4 months ago, but with the latest splash image.

**How do I use Test Flight to show people my latest build?**

Comment: I would clear out the derived data and do build, then archive it. (`rm -rf /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried deleting all the derived data, cleaned, updated the build number, then build , then archived, then uploaded the app.  Test flight shows the updated build number, but everyone downloading the app from test flight is still seeing the version from several months ago.  Is there a way to preview the app/build file that Window Organizer submits to xcode to make sure the right file is indeed being sent along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that react-native projects requires a few extra steps for an iOS build.  You have to create a mainjs.bundle.

Instructions listed here:

[react-native iOS app not showing static assets (images) after deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354998/react-native-ios-app-not-showing-static-assets-images-after-deploying)