# ERROR: Apple silicon Macs support issue. The app has LSApplicationLaunchProhibited set to true. This is not supported on Mac, How to fix it?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-silicon

I got this error while trying to submit a sticker pack to the App Store:

> WARNING ITMS-90863: "Apple silicon Macs support issue. The app has LSApplicationLaunchProhibited set to true. This is not supported on Mac."

The sticker pack is not intended to be used on Macs, it is only for iPhones and iPads? How can I remove this warning so that I can upload it successfully? Because I also got this email afterwards:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Name of the App". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> ITMS-90863: Apple silicon Macs support issue - The app has LSApplicationLaunchProhibited set to true. This is not supported on Mac.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Any help or information to fix this issue?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

On the Apple App Store Connect website, go to your app > "Pricing and Availability".

Uncheck the checkbox under the section **iPhone and iPad Apps on Apple Silicon Macs** that reads:

> Apple Silicon Mac Availability -- Make this app available

If it's not available, then it shouldn't complain any further!

[image]

Comment: This is hardly an answer. It works if you don't want to include Apple Sillicon Macs but what if your app can be run on such devices?

Comment: Has anyone found the solution for cases where we want to provide the app for Apple Sillicon Macs

Comment: Thank you - this took away my headache - ha ha :)

Answer (score 5):

I still think the root error is in the Xcode/Connect connection, but you have to uncheck something that you can't see until you run the whole build/archive/deploy thing. After you validate/distribute, then go to your app on the Apple Connect Website. Find "Pricing and Availability," and you will find a checkbox:
"Apple Silicon Mac Availability - Make this app available"

Uncheck this.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow All below Steps to Completely Remove this issue :**

1. Go to your App - Pricing & Availability section on App store
2. Uncheck the checkbox Under this title "iPhone and iPad Apps on Apple Silicon Macs"

[image]

3. Save the changes
4. Go to Xcode, Change the Build Number & Upload new Fresh build

**Important Note :**

- If you haven't uploaded new build & still you are testing with the Old build than you will find the same issue exist there. So its mandatory to upload the new build after the above steps.

Hope this will help everyone to clearly understand & resolve the issue.