# ITMS-90747: Basic sticker pack with no code, yet App Store Connect thinks there's 32bit code in there

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode12, apple-silicon

Received this error:
ITMS-90863: Apple silicon Macs support issue - The app has LSApplicationLaunchProhibited set to true. This is not supported on Mac.

ITMS-90747: Architecture incompatible with MinimumOSVersion. The app bundle specifies a MinimumOSVersion of '14.1' but contains a 32-bit architecture that is unsupported on iOS 12 and later.

I have seen the first warning addressed elsewhere (with no answer yet) but I'm getting both errors, always together, and they feel like they might be related.

The first thing I noticed was that the Project Document was set to Project Format Xcode 9.3-compatible, so I changed that to Xcode 12, thinking that would eliminate the 32 bit problem. But that had no impact.

The Targeted Device Families are iPhone and iPad only, and I have toggled the iOS Deployment Target from 10.0 through 14.0, and that hasn't changed anything, either.

And cmd-F'ing "LSApplicationLaunchProhibited" isn't finding anything I can switch to false to test that.

Bottom line: Simple sticker pack, so there was zero code written, beyond setting up targets and the document settings. It shouldn't be generating a 32 bit version of anything and shouldn't be messing around with Mac Apple Silicon issues, and yet here we are.

First time here, so thanks for obliging these newbie questions!

*Footnote: Half of my question was asked here

[ERROR: Apple silicon Macs support issue. The app has LSApplicationLaunchProhibited set to true. This is not supported on Mac, How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833362/error-apple-silicon-macs-support-issue-the-app-has-lsapplicationlaunchprohibit)

... so if someone answers here I'll share it there.

Update:

I think I fixed the 32 bit part of the problem, but the solution is counter-intuitive (at least to me). By changing the deployment target to iOS 10, I got it through AppStoreConnect without the 32 bit warning.

But I'm still getting the Apple silicon warning ...

Comment: +1 thanks for the tip on the iOS 10 target. Still having the same issue on `LSApplicationLaunchProhibited` flag on a Sticker pack here too.

Comment: Hi, have you find a better solution to the 32-bit issue? I'm having the same issue with sticker pack but I can't changing the project's deployment target to a lower version because some of the libraries I'm using requires iOS 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your app on the Apple Connect Website

Under Pricing and Availability you will find a checkbox "Apple Silicon Mac Availability - Make this app available"

If you uncheck this it should stop giving you the apple silicon warnings

Comment: Thanks!  FYI, I also posted your answer to a similar question in the Apple dev forum.