# (Stickerpack for iOS Messages deployment error) WARNING ITMS-90863: "Apple silicon Macs support issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-stickers

Upon attempting to "Distribute App" archive in xCode, I get this error:
WARNING ITMS-90863: "Apple silicon Macs support issue. The app has LSApplicationLaunchProhibited set to true. This is not supported on Mac."

I have iPhone and iPad checked, but not MacOS. It is my understanding that stand-alone stickerpacks are not supported on Big Sur yet (nor has there been a hint that this will ever happen).

These projects were made using the StickerPack template in Xcode - not as an iMessage application - so there is zero coding involved on my end. I set the deployment target. I added the accessibility info - but that is it. I have no code on my end to toggle or fiddle with.

This is a VERY new error which surfaced as of Tuesday. I believe this is on Apple's end - some sort of update on their servers, because I had already successfully uploaded a stickerpack to the AppStore through AppConnect w/ the same version of Xcode a day before.

I already had 5 sticker packs published in the App Store for the past 3 years. I published updates to 2 of them literally just days ago. Then they had the Apple Event on Nov. 10 about Silicate macs and literally the next evening I got this error when trying to update another stickerpack.

I learned from previous errors before this that you need to make your product deployment target as 10.x because anything higher will give you a completely different error about 32 bit and 64 bit architecture. I dealt with that crap for over a week before I figured it out. That's what happens when you don't touch xCode for 2 years. Oops!

So after the error I cited showed up;

1. I tried creating a brand new version of the sticker pack from scratch that I was trying to update - since all I had to do was drag in my assets and re-type in all the accessibility tags for the visually impaired. Still no go.
2. So then, I updated to Big Sur - installation successful. Still no joy.
3. Then I updated Xcode after Big Sur. Successful updating, but *still* no joy.

I created a new archive w/ a different build number. Validated it successfully - but it failed AGAIN with the error I cited above. I've searched the Internet for an answer or a clue w/o success, but I think this is so new, a lot of people haven't figured this out yet. I'm waving my white flag now.

Comment: This might be the type of thing you need to sort out with Apple directly. I'm working on my first sticker pack submission this weekend, but it will be an extension of an existing app. There is a reasonable chance that the Big Sur launch changed App Connection's type-of-submission handling, and standalone sticker packs was broken.

Answer (score 0):

see the answer I posted to [ITMS-90747: Basic sticker pack with no code, yet App Store Connect thinks there's 32bit code in there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64836979/itms-90747-basic-sticker-pack-with-no-code-yet-app-store-connect-thinks-there/65026538#65026538)

(Apparently I'm not allowed to share the same answer to multiple posts about the same issue. Everyone is looking for this solution and I want it to be known!)

In short: You can opt out of the Apple Silicon Mac on the connect hub website, under availability and pricing