# Apple silicon Macs support issue - The app links with libraries that are not present on Mac

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Apple appstore replied me with following error, for my iOS build (for iPhone and iPad devices only) that I submitted on store for beta release.

> Apple silicon Macs support issue - The app links with libraries that
> are not present on Mac:
>
> @rpath/libswift_Concurrency.dylib

Could not find any solution or relevant documents from Apple.

Related Question on Stackoverflow: [ERROR: Apple silicon Macs support issue. The app has LSApplicationLaunchProhibited set to true. This is not supported on Mac, How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833362/error-apple-silicon-macs-support-issue-the-app-has-lsapplicationlaunchprohibit)

Comment: I found something here and trying it: https://forums.swift.org/t/app-distributed-via-testflight-crashes-on-launch/53936

Comment: Yes! That Forums link looks very promising. Do try the new RC Xcode release, it fixes a lot of stuff.